# Boost Logging Lib samples can't link in release mode

Tags: c++, boost

The library which can be downloaded as an additional package for boost, is [here](http://www.torjo.com/log2/).
It comes with a bunch of samples but the set up i have used so far in my own project is the one as dll (\logging\samples\dll_and_exe). Using VC9 I have no problems building & running the samples in DEBUG mode (same goes for my own project), but for the RELEASE mode my project complains with this error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct boost::logging::logger_format_write<struct boost::logging::default_,struct boost::logging::default_,struct boost::logging::writer::threading::ts_write,struct boost::logging::default_,struct boost::logging::lock_resource_finder::single_thread> * __cdecl g_dll_l(void)" (__imp_?g_dll_l@@YAPAU?$logger_format_write@Udefault_@logging@boost@@U123@Uts_write@threading@writer@23@U123@Usingle_thread@lock_resource_finder@23@@logging@boost@@XZ)
```

The logging samples uses few macros that are not mentioned in the tutorials (_CONSOLE being the most important), but fiddling with those macros doesn't seem to fix anything, the RunTime Library seems fine (MD, did also try MT no luck). It behaves as if the *.lib wasn't specified , but is set up. My guess would be a macro inside somewhere in the library for the Release mode. Suspect also about a thread problem, by reading the linker error, but considering the DEBUG build is flawless and I'm not using multi-threading... hmmm
Hope anyone can help me, will be looking for it...

Comment: Finally found that the macro NDEBUG is absolutely necessary for the RELEASE mode to be linked. Thanks.

Comment: Somehow the _CONSOLE and BOOST_LOG_COMPILE_FAST_OFF seem related, but can pin out for sure.

Comment: Your direction of using the NDEBUG macro saved my life. Lost 5 hours of my life trying to solve that, you should answer your own question with that!